# ESXi shell scripting getting rid of a message

Tags: shell, if-statement, esxi

I'm working on a small VMware ESXi project (personal project, not for any company).
Im trying to build a html file that contains a table with some information from ESXi OS, like time/date, OS version, patch number, etc.
However there are some commands that give no output and then my table has an empty box (cell).
What i am trying to do..and terribly failing at ...is that i am trying to put a simple if-else-fi statement in the shell script that would check if the output is empty or not.
Here is the command i use the check if there is an output to the command or not:

```
if [ $(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}') != " "  ]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi
```

The problem with this is, that while it gives the correct result, it also prints out the following:

```
sh:  : unknown operand
Empty!
```

Yes, the result is supposed to be "Empty!", but i cant get rid of the "sh: : unknown operand" message.
It seems it does not like that the != operand is not close to ")".

If however i put the "!=" operand close to the ")", like this:

```
if [ $(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}')!=" "  ]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi
```

..it no longer gives the "sh: : unknown operand" message but it gives the wrong result "Not Empty!".
If however i insert a command in the if-else-fi statement that gives an output, for example:

```
if [ $(esxcli system time get) != " "  ]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi
```

..it give no "sh: : unknown operand" messages and gives the correct result as "Not Empty!"

I have tried in the following ways but it gave the same "sh: : unknown operand" message:

```
if [[ $(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}') != " "  ]]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi

if [ -n $(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}') ]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi

if [ -z $(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}') ]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi

if "$(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}')" == " " ; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi

if $(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}')==" "; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi
```

How can i get rid of that message...What else can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `$(esxcli ...)` command expression produces no output then the shell is asked to evaluate this:

```
  if [   != " " ] ; then ...
```

and that's not a well-formed expression.  To fix, put double-quotes around the `esxcli` command expression (outside the parens), like this:

```
  if [ "$(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}')" != " "  ]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi
```

When you do that, if the output of the expression is empty the shell sees:

```
  if [ "" != " " ] ; then ...
```

which is an expression that it can understand.

Notice that the empty string `""` will not match the single space `" "` that you currently have on the right-hand side of the `!=`.  You will want to change that space to an empty string, or switch to using the `-z` operator ("is the following a zero-length string?") or the `-n` operator ("is the following a non-empty string?"), depending on which one fits your program logic. `-n` is what your existing logic wants, and it would look like this:

```
  if [ -n "$(esxcli hardware ipmi bmc get |grep -i gate |awk '{print $2}')" ]; then echo "Not Empty!"; else echo "Empty!"; fi
```

Notice that you still need to use double-quotes around the command expression.

Comment: YES!! That was it! once i put double-quotes around the $(esxcli..) command and changed the " " to "" it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!